# how to make a dictionaries to be csv

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

when I use the below code i get dictionaries, but when i try to make it to csv by panda, I met troubles: the code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\zhang\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get( "http://quotes.toscrape.com/")
from scrapy.selector import Selector
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
for quote in sel.css("div.quote"):
   text = quote.css("span.text::text").extract_first()
   author = quote.css("small.author::text").extract_first()
   tags = quote.css("div.tags a.tag::text").extract()
   print(dict(text=text, author=author, tags=tags))
```

run above code, i get the result as below:

---

```
{'text': u'\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d', 'tags': [u'change', u'deep-thoughts', u'thinking', u'world'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
{'text': u'\u201cIt is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.\u201d', 'tags': [u'abilities', u'choices'], 'author': u'J.K. Rowling'}
{'text': u'\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d', 'tags': [u'inspirational', u'life', u'live', u'miracle', u'miracles'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
{'text': u'\u201cThe person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.\u201d', 'tags': [u'aliteracy', u'books', u'classic', u'humor'], 'author': u'Jane Austen'}
{'text': u"\u201cImperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.\u201d", 'tags': [u'be-yourself', u'inspirational'], 'author': u'Marilyn Monroe'}
{'text': u'\u201cTry not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.\u201d', 'tags': [u'adulthood', u'success', u'value'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
{'text': u'\u201cIt is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.\u201d', 'tags': [u'life', u'love'], 'author': u'Andr\xe9 Gide'}
{'text': u"\u201cI have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.\u201d", 'tags': [u'edison', u'failure', u'inspirational', u'paraphrased'], 'author': u'Thomas A. Edison'}
{'text': u"\u201cA woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.\u201d", 'tags': [u'misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt'], 'author': u'Eleanor Roosevelt'}
{'text': u'\u201cA day without sunshine is like, you know, night.\u201d', 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'], 'author': u'Steve Martin'}
```

---

Then `x = dict(text=text, author=author, tags=tags)`
but print `x`
the `x` only show the last dictionary:

```
{'text': u'\u201cA day without sunshine is like, you know, night.\u201d', 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'], 'author': u'Steve Martin'}
```

So can any one tell me what is the reason?

Comment: it's because at every iteration, you rewrite the content of x as the keys (text, author, tags) are the same. So you can see it as he dictionary x is "updated" with the value for theses keys, at the end, you keep only the values for the last iteration. is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you rewrite the content of x as the keys (text, author, tags) are the same at each iteration, so to keep all the data, you can do:

```
dict_x = {}
index_nb = 0
for quote in sel.css("div.quote"):
   text = quote.css("span.text::text").extract_first()
   author = quote.css("small.author::text").extract_first()
   tags = quote.css("div.tags a.tag::text").extract()
   dict_x[index_nb] = dict(text=text, author=author, tags=tags)
   index_nb += 1
```

and then your df can be created like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_x, orient='index')
```

and you have each row a quote, and with data for columns text, author and tags

You can create the csv by `df.to_csv('file_name.csv')` add some [parameters according to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) if you want a specific format for your output